# Is using rand() in an INSERT statement also slow?

Tags: mysql, random, auto-increment

The MYSQL rand() function is notoriously slow in select statements, is this true for insert statements as well?  I would like to insert a new row with random number in the following way:

```
insert into new_table (field1, field2, randomField) values ('Hello', 'Ola', rand());
```

Will the rand() function become slow as the table gets larger and larger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the rand() function become slow as the table gets larger and larger?

No. RAND() getting slower on big tables is usually when it is used in conjunction with `ORDER BY` or `WHERE`. In your example, you are making *one* call to `RAND()` which will not be a performance problem.

Comment: Indeed, and it's only slow in `ORDER BY` (and potentially `WHERE`) because it defeats MySQL's abaility to use an index to pick or sort the data. The `RAND()` call itself is cheap.